# Can't hold session values

Tags: php, session, apache2, session-variables

I have written a code for a login page and user page. When the user provides the correct username and password, my code creates a session variable rid and then redirects the user to user page.

But I am facing a weird problem, the session variable remains in the login page but when the code redirects to user page is says `Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in /var/www/Avatar/test1.php on line 6`.

Just to check if session is working properly I tries to output `$_SESSION['rid']` on both the pages, it displays the rid on the login page, but on the user page I get the above error.

So I have created two sample pages `test.php` and `test1.php`. I am creating a session variable in `test.php` and then trying to display in in `test1.php`.

**test.php :**

```
<?php
     $result=session_start();
     $_SESSION["Searock"]="Searock";
     echo $result;
     echo $_SESSION["Searock"];
?>
<html>
     <body>
          <a href="test1.php">next</a>
     </body>
</html>
```

**Output :**

> 1 Searock next

**test1.php :**

```
<?php
    echo $_SESSION["Searock"];
?>
```

**Output :**

> Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION
>   in /var/www/Avatar/test1.php on line 2

I don't know whether the problem is in my code or is it in PHP enviroment variables.

Heres a screen shot of phpinfo.
[image]

Can someone point me in a right direction ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless [*session.auto_start*](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) is enabled, you need to call [`session_start`](http://php.net/session_start) explicitly on every page you want the session to be available.

So call `session_start` in *test1.php* and check whether `$_SESSION["Searock"]` exists before accessing it:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION["Searock"])) {
        echo $_SESSION["Searock"];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your test1.php file, you are missing [`session_start()`](http://php.net/session_start):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION["Searock"];
?>
```

You will need to have `session_start()` on top on any file you are using session related functions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call session_start() on each page. This will either begin a new session or resume a previously saved session. Do this before trying to access any $_SESSION variables and you should be good to go.

**Update**

Looks like I was beaten to it!